# How to extract table browser results from ucsc genome browser by scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I would like to automate the process of extracting information from the UCSC genome browser to save a lot of manual input. The following code gets to what I think is the right part of the form but I cannot extract the results:

```
 from mechanize import Browser
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import re

 br = Browser()
 url = 'http://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=201790284_dkwVYFu7V6ISmTzFGlXzo23aUhXk'
 br.set_handle_robots( False )

 for form in br.forms():
      if form['position']:
           print form['position']
           form['position'] = 'chr9:21802635-21865969'
           print form['position']
           break

 for form in br.forms():
     if form['hgta_doTopSubmit']:
          br.submit()
```

The first part works fine and changes the position of the genome to be queried. The second part doesn't seem to submit anything. It returns this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Silvia\Desktop\Copy\web_scraping\UCSC\table_browser_form.py", line 26, in 
    br.submit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 530, in click
    request = self.form.click(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Manually the website returns a screen of text corresponding to details about this location but I cannot seem to extract it here. Does anyone have any advise of how to get around this? I just need to store the result of what the output is - equivalent to the user pressing 'get results' on the website. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make the request using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

url = 'http://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=201790284_dkwVYFu7V6ISmTzFGlXzo23aUhXk'    
session = requests.Session()

params = {
    'hgsid': '201790284_dkwVYFu7V6ISmTzFGlXzo23aUhXk',
    'jsh_pageVertPos': '0',
    'clade': 'mammal',
    'org': 'Human',
    'db': 'hg19',
    'hgta_group': 'genes',
    'hgta_track': 'refGene',
    'hgta_table': 'refFlat',
    'hgta_regionType': 'range',
    'position': 'chr9:21802635-21865969',
    'hgta_outputType': 'gff',
    'boolshad.sendToGalaxy': '0',
    'boolshad.sendToGreat': '0',
    'boolshad.sendToGenomeSpace': '0',
    'hgta_outFileName': '',
    'hgta_compressType': 'none',
    'hgta_doTopSubmit': 'get output'
}

response = session.post(url, data=params)
print response.content
```

Prints:

```
chr9    hg19_refFlat    start_codon 21802748    21802750    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "MTAP"; transcript_id "MTAP"; 
chr9    hg19_refFlat    CDS 21802748    21802780    0.000000    +   0   gene_id "MTAP"; transcript_id "MTAP"; 
chr9    hg19_refFlat    exon    21802635    21802780    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "MTAP"; transcript_id "MTAP"; 
chr9    hg19_refFlat    CDS 21815432    21815518    0.000000    +   0   gene_id "MTAP"; transcript_id "MTAP"; 
...
chr9    hg19_refFlat    exon    21861975    21865969    0.000000    +   .   gene_id "MTAP"; transcript_id "MTAP";
```